# Where does the ASP.NET development server keep its logs?

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging, cassini

I am trying to sort out a problem where some relative urls are not resolving properly in an ASP.NET website. I want to see the HTTP logs to determine which URLs are being requested from the web server. I am using the ASP.NET Development Server, not IIS.

So are there logs produced by the ASP.NET Development Server where I can check which files are being requested?

Windows 7, 64bit
VS2008
ASP.NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by development server. Are you referring to the built-in Visual Studio server?

Comment: @Jeff: yes that is also called Cassini or Development Server.

Comment: @VoodooChild thanks. I knew Cassini but I didn't realize "Development Server" was official.

Comment: @Jeff: actually I am not sure if it is official as well and don't care. I remember it because there is a always a little balloon pops ups in your tray icon when you are using cassing which says something like "ASP.NET Development Server Started" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand Cassini has no logging feature

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to replace the basic ASP.NET development server that comes with Visual Studio...

[CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) includes a [real-time request/response viewer and logging facility](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Integrated%20request/response%20log%20and%20viewer&referringTitle=Documentation).  As I understand it you can [drop it in as a replacement web server](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Studio%202008/2010%20Development%20server%20drop-in%20replacement&referringTitle=Documentation) very easily.

[image: CassiniDev Log Viewer]

CassiniDev seems to do exactly what you need.  If you absolutely cannot use IIS for your site this may be the only other option in terms of being able to generate a request log.

Comment: what do you mean "stuck with IIS as the only option"? Don't you mean that he will have to "Upgrade" to IIS? :)  ..Or give a reason why Cassini is a better choice in your opinion.

Comment: @VoodooChild: I've changed my summary statement to reflect the fact that this is an alternative to Cassini.  Whether or not @David is willing or able to use IIS in his situation is besides the point I think.  Personally I always prefer to use IIS to host my development web sites but I also understand that this may not always be possible or desired for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

There are no logs for the development server, aka: Cassini

I would highly recommend using the IIS web server, if the logging is a crucial to your needs.

Comment: +1 for the link and question comments. Though Zayar did beat you to the punch with the answer so he gets accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to IIS Express, it includes logging but even better it has support for Failed Request Tracing feature that will give you much more details.

See: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Answer (score 0):

[UltiDev Web Server Pro](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst633_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx), although it has no logging for now, when [running from command line](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst661_Debugging-your-web-app-with-UWS--or-just-hosting-the-app-from-command-line.aspx), it tells you exactly which file the request is mapped to:
[image: Request processing trace in UWS Pro]

Answer (score 0):

Uh, if you are patient and don't have too much chatter on your system, I was able to find errors in the Event Viewer under Application section. Look for category 'WebHost' to find them.